# Which letters does the German alphabet consist of?

Tags: history, terminology, umlaut, eszett

I mean the “official” or “traditional” alphabet, such as the one taught in schools to children. Is the ordering the same as English? Does it include *C,* which I notice never seems to show up in native-German words? Does it include *ü, ö, ä,* and *ß?* If so, where? Does that mean Germans think of the alphabet as having 30 letters? Or is it less than that with some of them considered variants?

It may seem like a silly question, but my wife was asking and I honestly don’t know because I don’t think I was ever taught these things in German class in college. I never thought about it at the time.

To clarify, the question is: How do native Germans¹ think about their alphabet? For example, Swedes drop *w* from their alphabet and tack *å, ä,* and *ö* onto the end. Spanish speakers consider *ñ* (and, depending on who you ask, *ch* and *ll*) to be a separate letter, but unlike the Swedes they have inserted these into the alphabet in dictionary order. They do not consider accented characters like *é* to be separate letters. Speaking from that context, how then do Germans think about their alphabet?

<sup>¹ Recognizing that there will be some variation between Germany, Austria, Switzerland, etc.</sup>

Comment: C shows up a lot, in combination with H and K.

Comment: But CK not at the beginning of words.

Comment: [Celle](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Celle).

Comment: Note that in old German maps you find Köln written as "Coelln", so how traditional shall it get?

Comment: @RegDwight: Coburg, Cottbus, Cochem, Calw, Crailsheim, Chemnitz, Cuxhaven ;)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I learned in school that the alphabet has 26 letters, A to Z, that was in the 1970s and 80s in Germany. Somehow the umlauts and the eszet were never mentioned when the alphabet was enumerated, I suppose because they are not considered proper letters in German.

As for the letter "c", we have plenty of them, but in german words they only occur in the combinations "sch", "ch" and "ck". These is no special handling for such combinations in german.

As for the ordering, in dictionaries and encyclopedias the umlauts are sorted like the base letter, e.g. "ä" is sorted like "a".  Only if there is a tie then "ä" is sorted after "a".  For example, "Sage" < "Säge" < "sagen" < "sägen".

In phone books umlauts are sorted like base letter + "e", e.g. "ä" is sorted as "ae", etc. This is because phone book contain proper names, which may be written either with umlaut or with base letter + "e", and the correct spelling is not always known. With this sort order such names are still easy to find.

Since you mentioned it, in the Swedish sort order "w" was considered a variant of "v" until 2006, and "ü" is still considered a variant of "y". Both letters were abolished from Swedish words in a relatively recent reform, but continue to exist in proper names.

**Edit:** Just heard [this little song](http://google.com/search?q=das+ist+das+ganze+abc) on [Arte](http://www.arte.tv/de/europeens/karambolage/3965014.html).

Comment: Might be nice to add an example of phone book ordering so to keep *Mueller* close to *Müller*, *Schaefer* next to *Schäfer* or w/e. Also, *ß* is considered a ligature, not a letter, which is why it doesn't show up. The *Umlauts* are probably best considered letter variants, much like accented Spanish letters. *ß* would be considered *ss* in phone books, so *Thissen* and *Thißen* show up together, wouldn't it?

Answer (score 28):

The German alphabet (in German "Deutsches Alphabet" or colloquial "A-B-C") is a variation of the Latin alphabet and includes **26 capitalized letters** (same as in English) plus the **umlauts** (Ä, Ö, Ü) and (only) in Germany and Austria the "scharfes S" (ß). The ß ist not part of the alphabet in Switzerland and Liechtenstein.

If you're referring to a single letter you're supposed to use the neutrum gender: "das A, das B, das C etc."

[image: German alphabet]

Note: when I went to school (1970s and 1980s) we used to recite the 26-letter alphabet and didn't add umlauts or the ß.

Comment: Ich möchte anmerken, dass in Österreich die Buchstagen J und Q auch als [jeː] und [kve:] ausgesprochen werden.

Comment: @Phira: Das hängt sehr stark von der Region ab. [je:] habe ich zum ersten Mal gehört, als ich nach Wien kam. In der Schule in Kärnten hieß es immer [jot].

Comment: Ich möchte anmerken, dass in Österreich der Buchstabe ß als [ˈʃaʁfəs ʔɛs] (»scharfes S«) ausgesprochen wird. Die Bezeichnung *Eszett* ist in Österreich nicht üblich.

Answer (score 14):

There is no such thing as a “German alphabet”, and while we are at it there is also no such thing as an “English alphabet” either. I don’t really know where this originated, but it appears to be perpetuated by American teachers. To my knowledge, no such concept ever got wide traction anywhere in the German-speaking area. Presumably, for a culture that actually *has* distinctive features in its writing system, there is less reason to come up with such terminology. (PS: Another explanation would be if such terminology once existed in German but was primarily applied to fraktur letters and cursive handwriting. Not too long ago, many older Germans still considered antiqua and the normal modern handwriting somewhat foreign. I don't know how to test this hypothesis.)

By þe way, in part you have þe Germans to þank for þe simplicity of “þe English alphabet”. Before þe English imported heaps of cheap printing presses from Germany in the 15th or 16th century, *þ* (thorn) and the rarer *ȝ* (yogh; used e.g. in McKenȝie but also in *þouȝ, ouȝt, bouȝt* etc.) were still widely used. Þe shiny new presses didn't come wiþ þese letters (þouȝ þey did have useless umlauts instead), and printers simply substituted *th* and *z/gh/y* for þem instead of paying for þe missing types.

There is such a thing as the Latin alphabet. In its modern standard version it consists of 26 letters A–Z. Some of them are of relatively recent, Central European (?) origin:

- The distinction of I and J is new. Originally this was just one letter.
- The distinction of U and V is new. Originally this was just one letter.
- The letter W is new. Originally this was the sequence VV or UU.

One of the original 23 letters was a 'foreign' letter even in Latin: *K* was originally an Etruscan letter that only appeared in Latin words of Etruscan origin. (The Etruscans were the previous big militaristic culture, which was then taken over by their former vassals, the Romans. Apparently the Etruscans distinguished two different *K* sounds, only one of which was represented by Latin *C*.)

Possibly caused (but at least much exacerbated) by the ubiquity of typewriters and later of computers that could only present the very restricted ASCII character set, there is a modern American tradition of totally rejecting not just modified Latin characters but even accented letters that have been fully part of English since practically forever. All major dictionaries are full of *English* words, mostly of French origin, whose standard spelling has an accent. They do, however, not always agree on the details. Sometimes the accented form is primary in one dictionary and secondary in the other, and for another word the roles are reversed. In many cases such as *resume* (the noun, not the verb) the accent is critical for fast and efficient communication, even in English. E.g., I only had to add “(the noun, not the verb)” because I used the non-standard, ersatz spelling for *resumé* which came to be accepted as correct only because sometimes technical difficulties prevent the better spelling. (By the way, *resumé* is **not** the French spelling of the word. The French spelling is *résumé*.)

There is of course such a thing as “the alphabet” as taught to German children. Usually it is presented starting with A–Z, then there is a separate block of the three umlauts *ä, ö,* and *ü,* and finally in a third block or at the end of the second, there is *ß.* This is also the normal order in which children recount the alphabet. Though usually they stop after the first block of 26 letters, or possibly after the second. Except for the lack of nationalist ideology, this is just like American children don’t mention *é* as part of “the English alphabet”.

### Accented and special letters; sorting

Here are two slightly more standard questions:

- The distinction between special letters added to the standard Latin alphabet, and accented versions of (standard or special) letters.
- The sort order when making lists. Fortunately this is less relevant nowadays than it once was.

Generally, an accent is something added at some stage to a letter in an existing spelling in order to distinguish it from other spellings, to indicate that another letter was dropped because it became silent, or for consistency with other spellings that were derived in one of the previous two ways. When it’s technically impossible to print an accent (as used to be the case often for capital letters), it’s acceptable to just drop it. An example is the diaeresis in the *English* word *coöperate* (*New Yorker* spelling).

The two dots in *ä, ö,* and *ü* are what remains of the letter *e* after generations of scribes placed it above the previous vowel in certain situations. When those letters cannot be printed correctly, the only acceptable work-around, ever, is to use *ae, oe,* or *ue* instead. Therefore, *ä, ö, ü* in German are not accented letters, and in particular they are not *a, o, u* with diaereses. They are special letters designed to be used with the Latin alphabet; they are modified Latin letters. Yet they are not full members of the alphabet.

Similarly, *ß* evolved out of a ligature for *sz* at a time when <s>German didn’t really distinguish *s* and *z*</s> *s* and *z* were used differently than today. The *z* in this context was later regularised to an *s* and isn’t optically recognisable anymore (because the *z* shape has changed), but the letter *ß* is still often called *s z* (usually spelled *Eszett*). When *ß* is not available, as is always the case when using capitals only since *ß* has no capital version¹, the only acceptable solution is to replace it by *ss*. (Definitely not by a single *s*, and definitely not by *β* (Greek beta), as is still often done in manuals produced in Asia.) The old alternative work-around of replacing it by *sz* (which is rare to occur otherwise and can be distinguished from naturally occurring *ss*) has fallen out of use.

<sub>¹ Technically, the lack of a capital version of ß has long been felt to be a problem, and therefore some people came up with uppercase variants of ß. They may be getting a bit more frequent in more modern fonts. However, even if your font has it and you can figure out a key combination to enter it, it's still eccentric to use it and people *will* notice. (Which is fine if you don't mind taking attention off the content of your text. Though most people will think it looks strange, hardly anyone will get into word rage over this.)</sub>

When it comes to sorting names, the standard German point of view is that *ä* is sorted as *ae* etc., and *ß* is sorted as *ss*. Things become tricky and very chaotic when you have to sort *Müller*, *Mueller*, *Müllermeister* and *Muellermeister*, for example. There is no established standard for handling this. (Of course there are standards. The problem is that there are too many of them and almost nobody knows when to apply which one.)

The fact that some other languages also make frequent use of letters that look like German umlauts causes additional difficulty. Danish *ø* is not one of them, but has the same function and much the same history (from *oe*) as German *ö*. So does Swedish *ö*. In Scandinavia, Danish *ø* and Swedish *ö* are probably considered fully equivalent variant forms of the same letter; I am just not sure if people distinguish them in names. In sorting, they come **after** *z*.

This creates all sorts of problems when you try to sort lots of author names. You must treat *ö* in a German name as *oe* and *ö* in an English or French word as *o*. You may decide to treat Swedish *ö* and maybe even Danish *ø* like German *ö*, but then whatever you do with Danish *å* will cause some inconsistency. Not to forget Finnish *ä*, Hungarian *öü*, Turkish *ü* and Chinese pinyin *ö*, which are all special letters but not umlauts, even though they look and sound exactly like the German umlauts².  Using the rules of the original language is no help if someone was born in one country and ended up in the other, possibly turning German *ö* in a German name of Danish origin into a Swedish *ö*.

<sub>² An umlaut is a specific type of modification of a base vowel for grammatical reasons which occurs in Germanic languages. Remnants in English: brother -> brethren, fall → fell, foot → feet, old → elder, long → length, full → fill. Nobody adopts umlauts, of course, but the graphical appearance of the German umlauts seems to be a big cultural export hit.</sub>

> Recognizing that there will be some variation between Germany, Austria, Switzerland, etc.

I am not aware of any variation between the German-speaking countries. There seems to be no reason for one anyway. Of course, *ß* is not used in Switzerland, but that just means that the most rarely mentioned part of the alphabet is never mentioned there. By the way, the practice of not using *ß* in Switzerland seems to have started only with typewriters. The reason is that Swiss typewriters had (and computer keyboards have) the same number of keys as English and German keyboards but need to accommodate more letters so that all four national languages can be typed easily. So they decided to leave out *ß* and the capital umlauts, starting a process of kicking them out altogether.

### Update: Capital *ß*

After capital versions of *ß* became increasingly available in fonts, and since they are important for correct all-capital spelling of names in passports, the international Council for German Orthography decided in 2017 that they now exist officially. However, capital *ß* is still just as hard to type on a German keyboard as any other exotic letter, and in particular harder than *é*. And it still looks pretty crappy in all fonts. So it seems best to continue avoiding it unless you really need it for technical reasons.

Comment: ß *is not available, as is always the case when using capitals only since* ß *has no capital version* – Typefaces with a capital *ß* exist since more than a hundred years (see [here](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Großes_ß)). You may think of its usage what you like, but as it is, the *always* is wrong.

Comment: *They are special letters designed to be used with the Latin alphabet; they are modified Latin letters. Yet they are not full members of the alphabet.* – So, how exactly are they different from, e.g., *w?*

Comment: *W* has become a naturalised member of what we call the Latin alphabet today. But the umlauts aren't conventionally counted even by German-speakers, just like accented letters aren't counted by French-speakers. That's what I mean by not being full members. Obviously the glyphs exist in fonts and such.

Comment: Capital *ß* is, and has always been, a rare oddity that is rarely used even when it happens to exist in a font, because normally there is no support for it and it looks just as wrong among the capital letters as *β* substituting *ß* does in a word. This is the sense in which, I insist, capital *ß* has never existed. Black swans also exist technically, but since they are rare freaks of nature, it's correct to say they don't.

Comment: *This is the sense in which, I insist, capital* ß *has never existed.* – But this is not the sense, in which you claim that it never existed in your answer. As I said, you can think about the capital *ß* what you like, but to claim that a capital *ß* is never available is not true.

Comment: This is a bit late, but: Obviously I used *always* not in the absolute sense but in a contrastive manner. *ß* is sometimes not available at all, sometime it's just hard to enter, and sometimes it's fully supported. But support for its capital variant is almost non-existent except for some fonts (but no keyboard mappings) containing it. And when it's supported, most people don't use it because they don't know it's supported, don't know how to enter it, aren't sure if it's even correct to use it, or because it just looks wrong. (Even more so than the *ö* in *coöperate* does.)

Comment: I added a footnote to explain this point. (I think it's even more clear now that in context, *always* is not the quantifier of formal logic but the normal English word, which permits exception so long as they are rare compared to an unstated but not completely arbitrary standard.)

Comment: Regarding sorting: ä, ö and ü are treated as identical to a, o and u when sorting anything but names, see DIN 5007

Comment: @adhominem: The problem is that there is more than one norm and that even in Germany norms are not universally adhered to - especially in situations where they aren't adequate. My information wasn't from Wikipedia but from a paper which, IIRC, was presented by a librarian for a conference on this kind of problem with sorting.

Comment: @HansAdler My personal experience with dictionaries, book indexes and software development is that Umlauts tend to be sorted with their non-Umlaut letters, as that is the default sorting. Outside of the DIN, I have personally never come across the version where Umlauts are sorted with the -e suffix. I can see how it makes sense for names, though.

Comment: @adhominem: My personal experience at the time when sorting was still more relevant because you had to understand it to find certain entries in dictionaries, telephone directories and physical library catalogues was that the situation was chaotic and especially the latter tended to be inconsistent or at least hard to understand. I guess another case where the -e sorting makes sense is probably book titles in a Swiss library, where some will involve capital umlauts that are, or were, sometimes printed that way.

Comment: Practically, there is phonebook order and dictionary order. In phonebook order, you want Müller and Mueller sorted together, so ü = ue. In dictionary order, you want Arzt and Ärztekammer together, so A = Ä. Obviously you can't have both, so you need to decide which one you want.

Answer (score 6):

It is the same as yours.  26 letters and in the same order. The *Umlaute* ä, ö, ü where seen as modifications of a, o, u by [Diakritisches Zeichen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diacritic)   and *ß*  was not seen as full member of the *Alphabet*. The exact classification was a bit vague.

Later at university (mathematical linguistic) there was a strict differentiation between character set and alphabet. The first determines which letters are parts of words and the latter has the focus on sorting order.

Undoubtedly ä, ö, ü and ß are part of character set which is used by the German language.

The problem is that there where two different sorting orders for the *Umlaute* in use.

In Encyclopedic dictionaries ä, ö, ü where treated as modifications by diacritics and sorted like a, o, u  (or just behind them in case of ties) and the sort order by phone books, which treated them as synonym of ae, oe and ue.

EDIT:
In context of early computer without NLS support one had to be prepared for a sort order with äöü behind z, but that was a weakness of early machines.

@starblue thanks for correcting my memories.

Comment: German Wikipedia writes that the official alphabet is 26 + umlauts + ß in Germany + Austria: http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deutsches_Alphabet

Comment: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_orthography_reform_of_1996#Sounds_and_letters) contradicts this: " In reformed orthography the grapheme ß ... is considered a separate letter".

Comment: "The Umlaute ä, ö, ü where seen as modifications of a, o, u by Diakritisches Zeichen" - Notably, they are not "felt" as the same level of modification as accented vowels in most other Western languages I can think of are. Try the text message test: Many native speakers of French, Spanish, etc., would, when having to quickly write a text message with only ASCII characters available, silently drop all the accents. However, I cannot see a German speaker do the same; umlauts will usually be substituted with their two-letter replacement such as "ae", "oe", or "ue".

Answer (score 4):

#### Official

Ignoring the table of contents and the preface, the official German spelling rules begin with the following:

> Die Schreibung des Deutschen beruht auf einer Buchstabenschrift. Jeder Buchstabe existiert als Kleinbuchstabe und als Großbuchstabe (Ausnahme *ß*):
>
> *a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z ä ö ü ß*
> *A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z Ä Ö Ü*
>
> Die Umlautbuchstaben *ä, ö, ü* werden im Folgenden mit den Buchstaben *a, o, u* zusammen eingeordnet; *ß* nach *ss.* […]
>
> In Fremdwörtern und fremdsprachigen Eigennamen kommen außerdem Buchstaben mit zusätzlichen Zeichen sowie Ligaturen vor (zum Beispiel *ç, é, â, œ*).

To my knowledge, this is the only official source (and certainly the highest ranking official one) on what is a German letter and what isn’t. Essentially it states that the German orthography uses 30 letters and it does not make a distinction between *a–z,* the umlauts and *ß.* Furthermore it states that additional letters can be used for loanwords and foreign names.

While there is a statement about which sorting is used in the rules themselves, no sorting is prescribed. However there are [DIN norms for sorting](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alphabetische_Sortierung#Deutschland), namely DIN 5007 and DIN 31638. They suggest different sortings depending on the application (see [Starblue’s answer](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/1038/2594) for details), but do not define a sorting of the alphabet itself (which is not their purpose anyway) and thus yield no answer as to where *ä, ö, ü* and *ß* should be located.

#### Traditional

It’s tradition to exclude the umlauts and *ß* from the German alphabet, but that’s really just that: a tradition.

I guess most German speakers (and I have asked some) will answer that the German alphabet has 26 letters, because and only because that’s what they were taught in school. If there were an agreement to teach that the German alphabet has 30 letters, I am pretty sure you would get this as an answer – because for all orthographic purposes, they are full members of the German letter repertoire¹. The reason for this tradition lies in the fact that both the umlauts and the *ß* originally evolved from the Latin base letters; roughly: ae → ä, oe → ö, ue → ü, sz → ß.

However – and that’s my personal opinion – this tradition should be abolished as it is rather confusing to anybody learning our orthography. If we were to adhere to history, we could also not regard *w* as a separate letter, as it originates from *vv* or *uu,* respectively (and is younger than the *ß* by some criteria).

---

<sup>¹ Should anybody argue that they differ, because we have rules how to replace them when unavailable: That’s only because the other letters are hardly ever unavailable.</sup>

Comment: The Finnish way of counting letters backs the tradition argument: Finns consider the alphabet to have 29 letters (including *å, ä* and *ö*). However, only 28 are ever used in Finnish words and if you exclude loanwords, the number reduces itself a lot more (to 21, *g* only being present in the *ng* combination).

Comment: If you see things this way, the 'German alphabet' has more than 30 letters. By any reasonable standard, *das Café* has been a full member of the German language for a long time now, and there isn't really an acceptable way to spell the word without an accent. The dead keys for ' and ` on German typewriters and computer keyboards aren't just to make it easier to write French quotations and German names of Huguenot origin like *de Maizière*.

Comment: @HansAdler: I did not offer any opinion in my answer as to how many letters I want the German alphabet to have. But as you are asking: The contents of the alphabet only matter to school children and language learners anyway nowadays and for those, the 30-letter alphabet is certainly the least confusing choice in my opinion. You have to draw the line somewhere and there is a clear gap in frequency between the least frequent of the 30 (q) and the most frequent other letter (é), namely a factor of 27 going by dictionary entries.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft: Oops. I am not fully awake yet, apparently. - Thanks for the information. I wouldn't know how to test this easily, but I agree that a factor of 27 is definitely good enough for cutting off a statistics-based definition unless there are larger factors before (which I don't think is the case). I guess one should really test a natural corpus (minus names and foreign phrases) rather than a dictionary, or weight dictionary entries by their frequency, but presumably the result wouldn't be too different.

Answer (score -2):

The alphabet which is taught in schools is the same as the alphabet in English. The Umlaute and the ß are separated from the normal ABC.

Comment: Welcome. We value your contribution. Nevertheless, if you don't modify it, it will likely be removed by the community, since this answer doesn't state something not contained in other answers.

Comment: Also feel free to take a [tour] and consult the [help] in case of questions.